# aes-192-cbc - Get the password from Salt, Key, IV,

Tags: encryption, decryption

A friend has sent an encrypted file and gave the password to decrypt it.

`openssl enc -d -aes-192-cbc -in file.tar.gz.enc -p -out file.tar.gz`

When I use it, I'm getting errors

```
salt=ABC
key=DEF
iv =GHI 
bad decrypt
4570560108:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:533:
```

There is a file.tar.gz created, but when I try to unzip it, it is throwing an error.

```
tar xvzf file.tar.gz
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

The friend strongly says that he shared the correct password and showed the screenshot of the result(verbose).

If I have the Salt, IV and KEY. Is it possible to get the password using that?

P.S: I understand we could decrypt the file using IV and Key. Unfortunately, the decrypted file still shows "Unrecognized archive format".

Comment: 1) Do you know the encryption commando your friend used? Maybe he passed an explicit IV with the encryption
2) Do you know the openssl versions used for encrypting and decrypting?
3) Your error message indicates, that you are actually using libressl and not openssl for decryption

Comment: Not sure. He mentioned decrypting using this command though - openssl enc -d -aes-192-cbc